# Need to implement a key listener in selenium keyword driven framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, keylistener

How can I implement a key listener in selenium?

Requirement:

1) Before every test step, there is a key event(example right arrow in a key board).

2) After key event only, the test step has to be executed.

3) Every step in the test has to be executed after the mentioned key event.

Do we need to use AWT for this? 
We can't use Actions class and Keys enum in selenium because the event acts on Webdriver. So, could anyone please provide me a solution for this requirement?

Comment: You can use Robot Class.

Comment: Hi kishan, Robot class can be help ful for one time use. I need a solution for every step.

Comment: So why can't you use it in a loop using annotations. @Beforetest

Comment: I am not using any frameworks like testNg and junit.